# MmIsAddressValid function

Tags: windows, kernel

Microsoft says that this function should be used with caution but also says the following:

**"Even if MmIsAddressValid returns TRUE, accessing the address can cause page faults unless the memory has been locked down or the address is a valid nonpaged pool address."**

So naturally I was hoping to find out what exactly does the part about the memory having to be locked down really mean ? Are they referring to the implementation of spinlocks and/or raising the IRQL level when attempting to read from the memory address that is passed as a parameter to this API ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe they are talking about touching that address after `MmIsAddressValid` has returned true. Unless you did something to make sure the pages are going to remain valid, another thread could free/unmap the memory.

If you have a driver that receives a virtual address for example, just using `MmIsAddressValid` could lead to a [TOCTOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use) bug. Locking probably means calling `MmProbeAndLockPages`+`MmGetSystemAddressForMdlSafe` or similar functions.